# How are Herbrand structures used in logic programming

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I read in wikipedia that

> Herbrand structures play an important role in the foundations of logic programming.

How is that true? Can somebody give me an example on how they are used in the Warren Abstract Machine for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See e.g [Herbrand Semantics](http://logic.stanford.edu/herbrand/herbrand.html) and [Logic programming](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/8710/f03/ch2.pdf).